# Sql Update Row With Unique id

Tags: sql, mariadb

hello i would like to update a row in my database but want this row to be updated with a new unique id when its updated

example

```
sql = "UPDATE users SET username = 'timi' "
```

i would like timi to have a new unique id which mean if last id in the table is 5 i would want it to get a new unique id of 6
i dont want to write new sql to get the last id then increment and use. i want to use best practice
thanks

Comment: And what's your question about this? Is there any good reason to change the ID? What about all the other rows from other tables that reference that ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with a subquery to get the maximum ID from the table.

```
UPDATE users AS u
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid
    FROM users
) m
SET u.username = 'timi',
    u.id = m.maxid + 1
WHERE <condition to select the row to update>
```